# OpenCart 3.0.2.0 level 3 sub categories

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3

I am trying to create a lvl 3 sub menu on the categories menu with no success so far.

I added the below code to menu.php file inside the foreach loop lvl2

Catalog/controller/common/menu.php   file

```
// Level 3
 $grandchildren_data = array();
     $grandchildren = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($child['category_id']);
      foreach ($grandchildren as $grandchild) {
             $grandchild_filter_data = array(
                 'filter_category_id'  => $grandchild['category_id'],
                  'filter_sub_category' => true
             );
              $grandchildren_data[] = array(
                  'name'  => $grandchild['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($grandchild_filter_data) . ')' : ''),
                  'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $grandchild['category_id'])
                );
         }
```

And on the menu.twig file 
i added the below code inside the for loop for the child after the li > a

```
  {% if child.children %}
     <ul>
       {% for children in child.children %}
        <li><a href="{{ children.href }}">{{ children.name }}</a></li>
       {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
```

Any suggestions anyone?

Comment: does your model/catalog/category.php's getCategories return lvl 3 data?

Comment: @imox no it does not and i cant seem to figure out how to get the lvl 3!

Comment: what a/c to you is lvl3? can i see the model's getCategories function?

Comment: @imox i made a jsfiddle with the 2 function cause the code is too big for a comment!  https://jsfiddle.net/1bLLsu3u/

Comment: @tasor I will try to look into it, understand and help if i can

Comment: @imox  thanks a lot for even spending the time mate!

Comment: @tasor can you give example of lvl3 which you are trying to implement? One example could be Academics>class>class 1? go to qriyo.com see the categories. is this what you want?

Comment: @imox thats exactly what i want!

Comment: @tasor I can help you but i would need to ask a lot of questions and files. =D  do you have slack or anything?

Comment: check this @ https://www.pearlbells.co.uk/third-level-category-menu-opencart/

Comment: @imox sorry for being so late to respond, busy at work! I will check out the link you shared! U already did more than enough mate, cant thank you enough!

Comment: you can always comment back @tasor for any clarification. glad and happy to help

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**Controller**:
catalog\controller\common\menu.php

```
<?php
class ControllerCommonMenu extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load->language('common/menu');

        // Menu
        $this->load->model('catalog/category');

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

        $data['categories'] = array();

        $categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);

        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            if ($category['top']) {
                // Level 2
                $children_data = array();

                $children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);

                foreach ($children as $child) {

                    // Level 3
                    $grandchildren_data = array();

                    $grandchildren = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($child['category_id']);

                    foreach ($grandchildren as $grandchild) {

                        $grandchild_filter_data = array(
                            'filter_category_id'  => $grandchild['category_id'],
                            'filter_sub_category' => true
                        );

                        $grandchildren_data[] = array(
                            'name'  => $grandchild['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($grandchild_filter_data) . ')' : ''),
                            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $grandchild['category_id'])
                        );
                    }


                    $filter_data = array(
                        'filter_category_id'  => $child['category_id'],
                        'filter_sub_category' => true
                    );

                    $children_data[] = array(
                        'name'  => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
                        'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id']),
                        'children' => $grandchildren_data,
                    );
                }

                // Level 1
                $data['categories'][] = array(
                    'name'     => $category['name'],
                    'children' => $children_data,
                    'column'   => $category['column'] ? $category['column'] : 1,
                    'href'     => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
                );
            }
        }

        return $this->load->view('common/menu', $data);
    }
}
```

**View**:
catalog\view\theme\default\template\common\menu.twig

```
{% if categories %}
<div class="container">
  <nav id="menu" class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-header"><span id="category" class="visible-xs">{{ text_category }}</span>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        {% for category in categories %}
        {% if category.children %}
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="{{ category.href }}" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ category.name }}</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <div class="dropdown-inner"> {% for children in category.children|batch(category.children|length / category.column|round(1, 'ceil')) %}
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                {% for child in children %}
                    <li><a href="{{ child.href }}">{{ child.name }}</a>
                        {% if child.children %}
                            <ul>
                                {% for children in child.children %}
                                    <li><a href="{{ children.href }}">{{ children.name }}</a></li>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </ul>
                        {% endif %}
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
              </ul>
              {% endfor %}</div>
            <a href="{{ category.href }}" class="see-all">{{ text_all }} {{ category.name }}</a> </div>
        </li>
        {% else %}
        <li><a href="{{ category.href }}">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Finally you may need to clear your caches, twig cache, ocmod caches, etc...

Comment: @DigiCart you are doing the same thing that i am, the problem comes from the fact that the model isn't returning lvl 3 categories.

Comment: @DigitCart i was trying to integrate this code with my code. but i am not able to get the 3rd level categories in the menu for the frontend. I have also cleared the cache and still it didnt work. can u please help. thanks

Comment: @KunalParekh, it's tested and it works, please double check your edits.

Comment: @DigitCart i did exactly whats shown here. updated the menu.php and menu.twig files accordingly in the correct folder destinations. This is the link to to my website (http://www.thetileco.com.au/) but its not working at all

Comment: @DigitCart I was trying to understand your code but I am not sure how is the grandchild is read on the menu.twig. I dont see anything mentioned in the menu.twig. can u please let me know. thanks